# Custom Package Importing Issues

Tags: java, oop, package

I am trying to create custom packages and i put in my other Program But when i import this Package that it will gives me error.

This is Custom Package File :

```
package Collage.Softwere;

public class IT{

    public void meth1(){
        System.out.println("This is method 1...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        IT obj = new IT();
        obj.meth1();
    }
}
```

This is Test file where I Import This Package :

```
import Collage.Softwere.IT;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        IT obj = new IT();
        obj.meth1(); 
    }
}
```

I get This error :

```
error: meth1() is not public in IT; cannot be accessed from outside package
    obj.meth1();
       ^1 error
```

MY directory set up is :

```
-->Package (Folder Name)
    --> College (Root Directory)
        -> Software (Sub Directory)
           * IT.class
           * CE.class

        -> Hardware (Sub Directory)
            * ME.class
            * AME.class
```

Comment: Please recheck the completeness of the code you've shared in the question. _Every_ source file should have a `package ...` line as the first line (like it is in the IT class). `Test` class seems to be missing it. Another point: in the packages structure there is no `Test` class specified. So, it's unclear, in what package that `Test` class resides. 

According to the error, `meth1()` is not public. But in your code it is `public void meth1()`. Please recheck if the code you shared here matches the code you're having problem with. Good luck!

Comment: I have Tried, But they will give me same error. I have define same Package in Test class but that is not working.

Comment: The package you define within the class source code should correspond with the path where your class source file resides in the file system. And so far it's not clear where Test class resides. Please update the code listing in your question so it exactly matches the code in you project. Alternatively you can consider sharing a source code via some git hosting (gitlab, github, bitbucket).

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the imports.

Collage.Softwere -> Collage.Software

Collage.Hardwere.ME -> Collage.Hardware.ME

if it isn't that typo, you need to make sure in your dependency management that the package is added as a dependency in the right pom.xml (if you're using maven).

Comment: Yeh , this is my mistake in asking a question but now they are fixed but my error is not solve.         If i use   ** java Collage.Software.IT **  in run time that will give me output nut when i importing package that time i get error.